# How to get the amplitude output of a single frequency from a Resonant Bandpass? (ie. Using a reso BP as an envelope...)

Tags: filters, bandpass, envelope

A resonant bandpass like this:

[image: Resonant Bandpass]

is resonating at a frequency of 125 Hz. You are controlling the decay time by modulating $Q$ accordingly. The BP is being excited by a MIDI triggered impulse.

At its resonant frequency it will decay at a natural rate of $ y= c^{-x}$, i.e. it will give a nice exponential decay.

Is there any way to get the output level of the bandpass at its resonant frequency (125 Hz)?

If it is possible to get the output/amplitude level at this specified frequency, one could use the bandpass as a synth envelope.

This might be a bit computationally expensive, but resonant BPs have some unique properties that might be fun to exploit if this is possible. I'd at least like to see what I could get out of it.

For reference, the resonant BP filter I'm using in my projects is the one here:

- https://github.com/JordanTHarris/VAStateVariableFilter/blob/master/Source/Effects/VAStateVariableFilter.h
- https://github.com/JordanTHarris/VAStateVariableFilter/blob/master/Source/Effects/VAStateVariableFilter.cpp

> From *The Art of VA Filter Design* by Vadim Zavalishin, TPT State
>   Variable Filter: TPT -> Topology Preserving Transform
>
> This filter is  based off of the trapezoidal integrator, which
>   produces a bilinear  transformation. This filter does the proper
>   cutoff prewarping needed  for the TPT structure, as explained by
>   Zavalishin. It also handles the  problem of delayless feedback loops
>   that the trapezoidal integrators  introduce.

Comment: It sounds a bit a like a second-order generalized integrator with a trapezoidal integrator...

Comment: http://yadda.icm.edu.pl/yadda/element/bwmeta1.element.baztech-1080ee48-9173-4664-8233-7537486027d1/c/moz_63_3_aee_2014.pdf